# http request every x seconds in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, rxjs

I'm trying to refresh an http call every x seconds in angular2.

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {

    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
      'content':'Please Wait'
    });
    loader.present().then(()=>{
      this.http.request('http://mywebserver.com/apps/random.php').map(res=> res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        loader.dismiss();
        this.fact = data;
      },err=>{
        loader.dismiss();
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Error!',
          subTitle: 'Please check your Internet Connectivity',
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
      alert.present();
    })
    })

  }
```

I get data when the page newly loads. But now my issue is refreshing the http call to get new data every x seconds

Comment: Do you want to display the loader each time you refresh the data as well?

Comment: no,i don't want to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Observable.interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html):

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
...
constructor(...) {
  Observable.interval(30000).subscribe(x => { // will execute every 30 seconds
    this.ionViewDidLoad();
  });
}
```

OR inside your `ionViewDidLoad` function:

```
Observable.interval(3000)
          .timeInterval()
          .flatMap(() => this.http.request('http://mywebserver.com/apps/random.php')
          .map(res=> res.json())
          .subscribe(data=>{
              console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
              loader.dismiss();
              this.fact = data;
            });
```

Edit to answer your comment. From the Rxjs docs:

> The timeInterval operator converts a source Observable into an
>   Observable that emits indications of the amount of time lapsed between
>   consecutive emissions of the source Observable. The first emission
>   from this new Observable indicates the amount of time lapsed between
>   the time when the observer subscribed to the Observable and the time
>   when the source Observable emitted its first item. There is no
>   corresponding emission marking the amount of time lapsed between the
>   last emission of the source Observable and the subsequent call to
>   onCompleted.
>
> timeInterval by default operates on the timeout [Scheduler](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html), but also
>   has a variant that allows you to specify the Scheduler by passing it
>   in as a parameter.

Basically in this case it would be the reactive/Rxjs way of JavaScript´s native `setInterval()` function.

Comment: What does the `timeInterval` do?

Answer (score 7):

I would create a separate service to make your http requests:

```
@Injectable()
export class RandomService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) { }

  getRandom() {
    return this.http.get('http://mywebserver.com/apps/random.php');
  }
}
```

Now you could simply call `randomService.getRandom()` inside of  `setInterval`, but you can also use observable operations (there is an `Observable.interval` for example) to handle this for you in `ionViewDidLoad`:

```
async function ionViewDidLoad() {
  let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
    content: 'Please Wait',
  });
  await loader.present();

  // x number of seconds
  this.interval$ = interval(x).pipe(
    // make first request right away; otherwise we have to wait x seconds before first one
    startWith(),

    // cancel previous request if it had not finished yet
    switchMap(() =>
      // catch the error inside to allow for a retry each time
      // you could also use `.catch` on the entire observable stream which will
      // cancel it if there's an error.
      this.randomService.getRandom().catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.alertCtrl
          .create({
            title: 'Error!',
            subTitle: 'Please check your Internet Connectivity',
            buttons: ['OK'],
          })
          .present();
      }),
    ),
  );

  this.interval$.subscribe(data => this.fact = data);

  // Separate observable to dismiss loader on first emission
  this.interval$.pipe(first()).subscribe(() => loader.dismiss());
}

ionViewWillUnload() {
  this.interval$.unsubscribe();
}
```

NOTE: this is assuming use of RxJS 5.5 and Angular with `HttpClient`. You may not have these, but you can still do something very similar. You just wouldn't be able to pipe with lettable operators and if you're not using `HttpClient` you still have to do `.map(data => data.json())` which I would do in the service.

Finally, avoid storing and manually unsubscribing if you can, as in `this.interval$`. Instead You might do something like `this.fact$ = interval(x)...` Then in your template you can do `*ngFor="let fact of (fact$ | async)"` and you don't have to unsubscribe manually.

Comment: This is perfect solution when your http is in a service called by another service for processing etc. Thanks!

Comment: As of Oct 2019 rxjs 6, `startWith()` will not trigger the call right away. We need to use `startWith(0)`