# how to call a method for every 30 seconds using Angular4 instead of Set interval

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

HI here i have a method from which i am getting the data here i want that data to be refreshed for every 30 seconds previously i used setINTERVAL method but instead of that can i use Observable Interval if so how can i use this becoz if go out of that page i want to unsubscribe  from that method

below is my code which get results

```
getOrderTrack(data){
    this.serv.OrderTrackDetails(data).subscribe(res=>{

       this.OrderTrack = res.CurrentOrderStatusResult;
       console.log(this.OrderTrack);
     },err=>{
       console.log(err);
     })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889114/http-request-every-x-seconds-in-angular?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http request every x seconds in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889114/http-request-every-x-seconds-in-angular)

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara ok here how can i unsubscribe the method name if go for next page bcoz i put this if go to the next page also it is calling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i use Observable Interval if so how can i use this becoz if go out
>   of that page i want to unsubscribe from that method

You can unsubscribe where you want. So, if you navigate to another page and this component will detroy, then**ngOnDestroy** lifecycle hook is called.

```
export class AppComponent {
  name: any = 'Angular 5';
  subscr: Subscription;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.subscr = Observable.interval(1000)
      .flatMap(() => this.getData())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data', data);
        this.name = data;
      });
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    this.subscr.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscr.unsubscribe();
  }
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-interval)

Answer (score 3):

Use unsubscribe in the ngDestroy, to unsubscribe the sunbscrition to the observable

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;
  this.subscription = // Observable code 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```